# How to log errors in Informatica?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, etl, informatica, informatica-powercenter

Due to security issues the **user or Informatica has grants to create neither tables nor synonyms**.

So I have come up with this:

1. The `PMERR_DATA`, `PMERR_MSG`, etc. tables are created under another user
2. The user of Informatica is granted to `select`, `inset`, `update` and `delete` from these tables
3. Name of the owner of the tables was set in the error table log prefix field:[image: informatica config task panel]

But when the task starts, the integration service tries to create these `PMERR%` tables and it fails (due to lack of permissions to create tables)

How can these restrictions be overcome?

Comment: Can you create synonyms in the Informatica schema that refer to the error log tables?  Maybe Informatica would think they already exist and use them without knowing it's in a different schema.

Comment: Unfortunately the user of Informatica is not granted to create synonyms. I thought I might create synonyms directly inside of Informatica, but I haven't found anything similar to it.

Comment: Can some other user create the objects for the Informatica schema?  I'm not sure how anyone expects you to use Informatica without granting any privileges.

Comment: Yes, you are right, if I don't find another solution, I will use this question as a justification to request all the necessary permissions.

Comment: Another idea - would it be possible to edit the connection information to run `alter session set current_schema = SCHEMA_WITH_ERROR_TABLES;`?  Informatica would still need object privileges on those tables, but would not need to own any objects or need any system privileges to create objects.